# Query Django ORM with foreign key fields

Tags: django

I am having issues with using Django ORM queries in order to retrieve specific information. I have three models all linked by foreign keys, these are Hosts, Groups and Organisations. So each host belong to a group and these groups belong to an organisation. I need to get the query set of all hosts that belong to a specific organisation named 'Y' for example. Below are my model.py, can anybody help me to formulate a query set that will achieve this? or point me in the correct direction to figure this out?

Hosts

```
class Host(models.Model):
host_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.host_name
```

Groups

```
class Group(models.Model):
org_name = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
group_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.group_name
```

Organizations

```
class Organization(models.Model):
org_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)
org_code = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True, default=GenerateOrganozationCode)

def __str__(self):
    return self.org_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
host_queryset = Host.objects.filter(group__org_name__org_name='Y')
```

For more detailed information and examples, please do refer to the [official django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Much simpler than I was expecting.